# Use push notifications also if user doesn't accept them

Tags: objective-c, push

I have a doubt about iPhone push notifications. I need to use them when the user is using the app, but for me aren't necessary alert-sound-badge when the app is closed.

My question is: could I use these kind of notifications also if the user doesn't accept the push notifications when the app starts?

I would to use the push system to avoid any timer to get periodically info from our server when the app is running; they will be custom notifications with no alert, no badge and no sound.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't circumvent the user's choice (the user said no, you should respect that). However, you can determine if the user opted out using

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    // user does not want to get push notifications
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. If user refuses the notifications, APNS server will not send them to the device. 
And by the way, trying to get application / user info from an app without asking for user permission may lead to application rejection from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't want to get application/user info. I only need to exchange custom messages with our server: the app is a chat, so i only want push to the user that there is a new message for him, so that the app can request to the server the new messages.

Comment: Well, if you are to use the APNS system, you beed user agreement. That would mean that if you want user to receive notifications while the applications is closed you need the APNS system. If you want your application only to work after being launched you can use threads and background activity. You can also have a listener to read from your server's messages. Or make the app to perform scheduled checks (every xx seconds). In that case you should really think of the timer you use as it has dramatic consequences on battery usage.

Comment: I know that a timer can cause a lot of problem on battery usage, for this reason I would to use the APNS. What I don't understand is how could I have a listener to read from the server's messages. Should I use "some kind" of server socket on the iPhone? or What?

Thanks